# ÙˆØµÙ„Ù‰ characters showing when writing the text obtained through web scraping into a csv file

Tags: python, csv, unicode, character-encoding

I have done web scraping from a website in Arabic for the purpose of using the text as my training data for NER; Now I am trying to write each word with its associated tag (whether a named entity or not) into a CSV file, but in the CSV file the Arabic words are shown with these characters: ÙˆØµÙ„Ù‰
How can I resolve this problem? I want the Arabic words to be shown in the Arabic script in my CSV file.

This is part of my code:

```
with open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

Comment: Is "ÙˆØµÙ„Ù‰" really UTF-8? You're facing issue while scraping or saving file? I believe we can manipulate that character while scraping rather then while writing in file

Comment: It's probably a viewer issue.  If reading the CSV with Excel, use `encoding='utf-8-sig'`. Excel assumes a localized encoding unless there is a UTF-8-encoded byte order mark (BOM) codepoint at the start of the file.  `ÙˆØµÙ„Ù‰` is Arabic characters encoded in UTF-8 but decoded in Windows-1252.

Comment: Thanks! I used encoding="utf-8-sig" and that just solved the problem :)

Comment: @Xitiz How do you think OP is looking at the generated CSV file to see the problem :^)

Comment: @MarkTolonen Don't know. :P